# Is it possible to use Facebook insights without publishing actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I need to use Facebook insights more of as analytics tool rather than promotional tool. I dont want to spam my users with lot of notifications on their walls but at the same time I want to gather as much information as I can for users usage on my website.

My website works on facebook data for a user and wanted to check out what features they like most but dont want to publish all these actions on their walls.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 0):

Insights can be retrieved only as an array. To read Insights you need

a generic access_token for the publicly available application_active_users metric
a generic app access_token for all Insights for that app
read_insights permissions for all apps, pages and domains owned by this user

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

Comment: Thanks nerowolfe. However my question is how can I avoid publishing stories to users timelines or home?

Comment: Did not understand why you need to publish? Just gather this info for example with FQL and all

Comment: I am new to insights. If we create any story for which we need analytics , it always publish that story to users timeline by default like "someone used something on app" I dont want user to know about these clicks